# If $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ , then there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\lambda (${$x\in\Bbb{R} : f(x)\ge a$}$) \le \frac Ca$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> If $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ , then there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
>
> $\lambda (${$x\in\Bbb{R} : f(x)\ge a$}$) \le \frac Ca$

Here is my attempt so far:

$\lambda (${$x\in\Bbb{R} : f(x)\ge a$}) = $\int_\Bbb{R} X_{f\ge a}d\lambda = \int_{f\ge a}1d\lambda$

First of all, does that hold?

Then, if you multiply everything by a, you get $\int_{f\ge a}ad\lambda$. How do I then show that it's smaller than C? I was thinking that maybe I could have an integral of $f<a$ and $f\ge a$ on one side and then, since I only have $f\ge a$ on the other side, it's smaller. But I'm a bit confused since we have a constant and the integral of $a$ on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

$$a  \lambda(\{x\in \mathbb{R}| f(x) \leq a\}) = \int_{f \geq a} a \leq \int_{f\geq a} f   $$

The RHS is bounded above by $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f| = C$$

Comment: could you please give more details for the last step please

Comment: why is it a constant?

Comment: $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ by definition means that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| = C < \infty$.

Comment: ohhhh right thanks!

Comment: Of course. This inequality also goes by Chebyshev's inequality. Or depending on your textbook is a specific case of Chebyshev's inequality.